# Как ПРАВИЛЬНО обновлять MSYS2

Tags: c++, windows, msys2

Уважаемые господа,
хочу прибегнуть к вашей помощи.

Я использую MSYS2 для разработки на C++, потому что g++ - наше всё :-) ( установлена windows 10 x64  ).

Время от времени хочется его обновить.

Процедура эта не простая (а что у нас просто?), и мне уже и советы уважаемый  HolyBlackCat давал, и  [страницу их вики про обновление](https://www.msys2.org/wiki/MSYS2-installation/) (раздел III) я уже зачитал до дыр.

Но... не выходит каменный цветок. Уже на втором компьютере всё кончается так:
начинаю обновляться. По инструкции. Получаю на экране картинку вот такого вот вида:

[image: msys2 - картинка перед тем, как он перестаёт запускаться]

"а теперь закройте это окно и запустите обновление заново" - так ведь здесь написано?

Я закрываю окно. Просто нажав на крестик.

После этого MSYS2 больше не запускается. Ни одним из описанных способов - ни через *.exe-шник, ни через msys2_shell.cmd.

Я удивляюсь: что бы это значило? Почему его, собаку, так сложно обновить? в конце концов, черт с ним, можно каждый раз сносить и ставить заново... но какая то это бесполезная и глупая работа.

Что же я делаю не так и что еще можно попробовать? Может, есть какой то "не столь радикальный способ обновления", после кторого всё не разваливается? Мне, в общем то, наплевать, свежий ли сам шелл - мне надо, чтобы компилятор и дебаггер обновились, ну и всякие пакеты с библиотеками.

Что еще может влиять на это? из не очень стандартных вещей на машинке установена консоль cmder, по моему это просто обертка вокруг conemu. Причем, она подменяет стандартную консоль винды (потому что стандартная - это ужас какой то). Но, вроде бы, на работу MSYS2 это влиять не должно.

Спасибо за советы!

Comment: *"Я использую MSYS2 для разработки на C++"* - месье знает толк

Comment: А какой командой обновляете-то? `pacman -Syuu`? Можно попробовать его опять переустановить: последняя версия вместо того, чтобы просить нажать на крестик, сама аннигилирует все работающие msys2-процессы. Может у вас в фоне что-то оставалось висеть, и ломало обновление...

Comment: А просто `pacman -Syu` и следом `pacman -Su` не работает? И терминал надо убить из диспетчера, а не крестиком.

Comment: @Croessmah А я на крестик всегда убивал, у меня работало...

Comment: Обновлять весь MSYS2 не обязательно , попробуй обновлять отдельными пакетами. Я обнавляю по мере необходимости отдельные пакеты , все работает корректно.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60637581 https://stackoverflow.com/q/36972968

Comment: Большое спасибо всем за советы. Уважаемый @вася, в том треде, на который Вы ссылаетесь, есть неплохое описание разных команд pacman, спасибо. Но то, с чего начинается тред - там советуют установить довольно старую версию mingw, лучше этого сейчас не делать, так как в наборе пакетов msys2 есть свеженькие компилятор и дебаггер. И что то типа pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc и pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gdb установит их в систему

Comment: Если то же самое воспроизводится на новой чистой установке, я бы зарепортил как баг...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, спасибо! Мне пришлось выполнить новую чистую установку, теперь буду на неё пристально посматривать... когда настанет время обновлять